# Use objectAtIndex:indexPath.row in ViewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsindexpath

I use an array (self.tableData) with `objectAtIndex:indexPath.row` for retrieving NSString.

Here is my code :

```
Person *person = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = person.fullName;
```

I would like to use person.fullName; in `ViewDidLoad` but I don't know how to make this. Sorry if it's a stupid question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad` you can access statically:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= [self.tableData count]; i++)
   Person *person = self.tableData[i];
   NSLog("name: %@",person.fullName);
}
```

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can access dynamically:

```
Person *person = self.tableData[indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = person.fullName;
```

Comment: @KelvisonMatias Thanks man, but Person has multiple value :     "<Person: 0x7f80ca7caac0>",
    "<Person: 0x7f80ca7cb6b0>",
    "<Person: 0x7f80ca7a2670>",
    "<Person: 0x7f80ca7cb7f0>",
    "<Person: 0x7f80ca7cb7c0>",
    "<Person: 0x7f80ca7b3ee0>",
    "<Person: 0x7f80ca7b8720>",
    "<Person: 0x7f80ca7bb390>" I would like to access every value, not one with "int position = 0"

Comment: thanks man ! :) it works with :     for (int i = 0; i < self.tableData.count; i++){
        Person *person = self.tableData[i];
    NSLog(@"name: %@",person.fullName);
    }

Comment: but the problem is I can't use it outside the loop :/

Comment: Instead 10.. `[self.tableData count]`

Comment: Yes, but how can I store this data in NSString for example and use it outside the loop ? (in ViewDidLoad) ?